# 502 Bad gateway with node, ajax, restful api on GET request

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to do a mysql query when clicking a button on my application without refreshing the page. I am getting a 502 bad gateway log on my chrome browser when I hit my "More Info" button.
Note: Some of the code below is used from a youtube video by Michael Cheng.

The code I have:

**staticPricing.js**

```
$(function() {
// GET/READ info FROM server
$('#getInfoMats-button').on('click', function () {
    // ajax GET request
    $.ajax({
        url: '/materials',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var tbodyEl = $('#tbodytest');

            tbodyEl.html('');

            response.result.forEach(function (result) {
                tbodyEl.append('\
                    <tr>\
                       <td>' + result.PricePerSheetORFt + '</td> \
                    </tr>\
                    ');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**pricingTable.js**

```
    // sql handler
    exports.sqlGetMaterialPricing = "SELECT PricePerSheetORFt FROM genericname.info_pricing WHERE 'Key' = ?;";


exports.getMaterial = function(req, res) {
    var weErrored = false;
    var post = {
        PricePerSheetORFt: req.body.PricePerSheetORFt
    };



    mySqlController.connection.query(exports.sqlGetMaterialPricing, post, '1',
        function(err, result, fields){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.code);
                weErrored = true; // setting the error to true, this is used to display a message on the front end

            }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
        });

}
```

**Route**

```
var pricingTable = require('../controllers/pricingTable');
app.get('/materials', pricingTable.getMaterial);
```

and

**pricingTable.hbs**

```
<script src="staticPricing.js"></script>

<tbody id="tbodytest">
            {{#each data}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{this.IGNORE}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.IGNORE}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.IGNORE}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <button id="getInfoMats-button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collpase{{this.Key}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                More Info
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse{{this.Key}}">
                            <div class="card card-block">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <p><strong>PricePerSheetORFt:</strong> {{this.PricePerSheetORFt}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
```

Please don't mind the this.IGNORE, I changed it for this question.

Comment: Your ajax call doesn't seem to send any data to the server, and had it sent something, it should have been JSON as that's what the contentType is set to. Yet, you're expecting `req.body.PricePerSheetORFt` on the server ?

Comment: Your AJAX request doesn't has a type specified as 'GET' and  it doesn't send any data into the route you have defined. But you are accessing PricePerSheetORFt in the request body as _PricePerSheetORFt: req.body.PricePerSheetORFt_ on your **pricingTable.js** file

Comment: From my understanding, I thought 'GET' was default and didn't have to specify in ajax. I edited it and put method: 'GET', right under url. I also removed the colon in the PricePerSheetORFt in the .hbs file. Still no luck, not working :(.

Comment: Again, how would you be getting `req.body.PricePerSheetORFt` when you're not sending something called `PricePerSheetORFt`? Also, as noted, `req.body` generally requires both a bodyparser and a POST request.

Comment: I think I see where I messed up. So under my $.ajax code in staticPricing.js,  I am adding data: JSON.stringify({ name: result.val() }),  right under contentType. I also changed the method to 'POST', and my route to app.post. I am also trying res.end(JSON.stringify(result)); in my pricingTable.js. Now I'm getting  Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (staticPricing.js:9) . So, what should I put for "data"?